# Some Firebase Push Notification Doesn't Send

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase

Push notification on my android app seem to work but not 100%, since when I send a Notification, I only receive some of it, and not all. Why is it like this? How do I debug if the notification was sent or not?

Comment: You tagged with Ionic. I don't think Firebase Notifications currently supports delivering to Ionic clients. I may be wrong, but without seeing the minimal code+steps to reproduce the problem, it's difficult to say anything more helpful.

Comment: it's actually working just an easy steps.. well up until now I still don't know what's the reason of some notification not being sent sometimes. But I'm guessing it's the internet connection since other receives the notification but some do not. I'm from Philippines btw so internet connection isn't good